# SqlDataAdapter.Fill() OverflowException

Tags: c#, sql, decimal, sqldataadapter

I need to get data from DB and execute the following code:

```
using (var dataRetrievingCommand = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection))
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable("DataTable");
    var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(dataRetrievingCommand);
    sda.Fill(dataTable); //OverflowException here
    return dataTable;
}
```

The problem is that some columns in database has type `decimal(38,10)`, `decimal(38, 0)` etc. Their values range is larger than `decimal`'s type in C#, that's why I get an `OverflowException`.

**Is there any way of selecting that data in C# without modifying SQL query and DB structure?**

If DB value precision is higher than C#'s, it is OK to round the value. if overflow occurs I'd like to see NULL instead, or any other mark that value can't be read.

**INVESTIGATION DETAILS:**

The question sounds like a popular, but I've found only [one thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/970258.aspx?error%20OverflowException%20on%20Sqldataadapter) on Microsoft forum with same problem and no answers there.

SQL Server Management studio 2008 itself can't display such values in edit data mode - it shows "" and doesn't allow editing those cells. 
[image]
But SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE commands works fine and displays all data.

Decimal columns with precision 28 or less works fine, but any higher-precision column fails, even if values don't cause overflow like decimal(38, 38) which could be just trimmed like nvarchar is trimmed on insert.

```
sda.ContinueUpdateOnError = true;
```

doesn't change anything. I think it is just not an update operation, so this property is ignored.

```
sda.FillError += (sender, args) =>
{
    args.Continue = true;
};
```

stops exception throwing, but no data is returned at all - just single meaningless row

```
 CaseName | Decimal_10_2 | Decimal_18_0 | Decimal_18_18 | Decimal_28_0 | Decimal_28_28 | Decimal_38_0 | Decimal_38_20 | Decimal_38_38 | Float | Int
----------+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------+----
 Null     |              |              |               |              |               |              |               |               |       |
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems I've found the solution on my own.

```
sda.ReturnProviderSpecificTypes = true;
```

After that DataTable cells contains values of types like `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal`, `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString` etc., which can be further converted to native .NET data types with custom error handling.

Then I check `Precision` and `Scale` properties of the SqlDecimal value and if required, use [SqlDecimal.AdjustScale()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldecimal.adjustscale%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to round the value. Result can be accessed via the `Value` property. See my implementation:

```
public struct DecimalEx
{
    private decimal m_Value;

    public decimal Value
    {
        get { return m_Value; }
    }

    private bool m_IsNull;

    public bool IsNull
    {
        get { return m_IsNull; }
    }

    private bool m_IsOverflow;

    public bool IsOverflow
    {
        get { return m_IsOverflow; }
    }

    private bool m_IsRounded;

    public bool IsRounded
    {
        get { return m_IsRounded; }
    }

    private bool m_IsPositive;

    public bool IsPositive
    {
        get { return m_IsPositive; }
    }

    public DecimalEx(decimal value)
    {
        m_Value = value;
        m_IsNull = false;
        m_IsOverflow = false;
        m_IsRounded = false;
        m_IsPositive = value >= 0;
    }

    public static explicit operator DecimalEx(SqlDecimal dbValue)
    {
        var result = new DecimalEx();
        if (dbValue.IsNull)
        {
            result.m_Value = 0;
            result.m_IsNull = true;
            result.m_IsOverflow = false;
            result.m_IsRounded = false;
            result.m_IsPositive = false;
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            result.m_IsNull = false;
            result.m_IsPositive = dbValue.IsPositive;
        }

        if (dbValue.Precision > 28)
        {
            result.m_IsRounded = true;

            if (dbValue.Precision - dbValue.Scale <= 28)
            {
                var adjustedValue = SqlDecimal.AdjustScale(dbValue, 28 - dbValue.Precision, true);
                result.m_Value = adjustedValue.Value;
                result.m_IsOverflow = false;
            }
            else
            {
                result.m_Value = 0;
                result.m_IsOverflow = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result.m_Value = dbValue.Value;
            result.m_IsRounded = false;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }

    public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        if (IsNull)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        if (IsOverflow)
        {
            return "###";
        }
        return Value.ToString(provider);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** be careful with AdjustScale method because it's documentation isn't accurate - `digits` parameter isn't the number of digits in the result value, but the change in the number of digits (so to reduce precision by two you must pass `digits=-2`)